# Have evolutionary algorithms been used for engineering design?

Tags: reference-request, genetic-algorithms, evolutionary-algorithms, constraint-satisfaction-problems

Recently, I've been looking recently into what uses AI - specifically evolutionary algorithms - may have in automating engineering design.  For a long time, there have been algorithms that solve constraint satisfaction problems, and, to me, it makes sense to consider engineering problems as a superset of constraint satisfaction problems.  In spite of this, I haven't been able to find any cases of engineering design being automated other than a couple of cases of genetic algorithms being used to optimise structural members.

So my question is, why can't I find any examples?

The first thing that springs to mind is that I just haven't been looking hard enough - if this is the case, could anyone point me in the right direction?

The other obvious answer is that it isn't a widely researched area - if so, why not?  Is it just due to lack of interest or are there technical hurdles (abstraction, complex logic & reasoning, etc.) that make this a much more difficult problem than computer vision, games, and so on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Examples of [GA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm) implementations:

1. NASA’s spacecraft [evolved antenna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolved_antenna)
2. Solution for [TSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) with a big number of connections. [Here](https://github.com/maoaiz/tsp-genetic-python) is an example with Python and [here](https://github.com/7lb/TSP) with C#.
3. From my experience, GA can be even used for a training of small artificial neural networks, but with less efficiency than with traditional deep learning approaches

Also, I heard about successful projects with using GA for scheduling, packing and  logistics

Therefore, everything, that can be represented in a form of digital chromosomes (can be serialized to and deserialized  back from a sequence of bits) and we can define a function to evaluate its efficiency – [fitness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitness_function) or [reward function](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/189067/how-to-make-a-reward-function-in-reinforcement-learning) can be optimized by using of GA